# Find and replace in Haskell

Tags: haskell, replace

I want to input a list of 2 element lists of characters (just letters) where the first element is a letter in a String (the second argument for findAndReplace) and the second is what I want it changed to. Is there already a function in Haskell that does a similar thing? Because this would help greatly!

Comment: What did you try? Where exactly did you stuck?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin!

Comment: There are some replace functions for Text (and for ByteString in the stringsearch package) but if you want to write one with the specific type you claimed, you'll have to write it yourself if you want to be efficient. The simplest would be to use `map` and `lookup` (in Data.List).

Comment: Here's a general solution to this problem: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you might want to use a list of tuples instead of a list of lists for your first input, since you specify a fixed length.  Tuples are fixed-length collections that can have mixed types, while lists are arbitrary-length collections of a single type:

```
myTuple = ('a', 'b') :: (Char, Char)
myTriple = ('a', 'b', 'c') :: (Char, Char, Char)
myList = ['a'..'z'] :: [Char]
```

Notice how I have to specify the type of each field of the tuples.  Also, `(Char, Char)` is *not* the same type as `(Char, Char, Char)`, they are not compatible.

So, with tuples, you can have your type signature for `replace` as:

```
replace :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String
```

And now this specifies with the type signature that it has to be a list of pairs of characters to find and replace, you won't have to deal with bad input, like if someone only gave a character to search for but not one to replace it with.

We now are passing in what is commonly referred to as an association list, and Haskell even has some built in functions for dealing with them in `Data.List` and `Data.Map`.  However, for this exercise I don't think we'll need it.

Right now you're wanting to solve this problem using a list of pairs, but it'd be easier if we solved it using just one pair:

```
replace1 :: (Char, Char) -> String -> String
replace1 (findChr, replaceChr) text = ?
```

Now, you want to check each character of `text` and if it's equal to `findChr`, you want to replace it with `replaceChr`, otherwise leave it alone.

```
replace1 (findChr, replaceChr) text = map (\c -> ...) text
```

I'll let you fill in the details (hint: if-then-else).

Then, you can use this to build your `replace` function using the simpler `replace1` function.  This should get you started, and if you still can't figure it out after a day or two, comment below and I'll give you another hint.

Comment: This is all totally redundant. OP wants to replace ONE character with ONE other character.

Comment: "I want to input a **list of 2 element lists of characters** where the first element is a letter ... and the second is what I want it changed to"

Comment: Well it depends. I want the facility to be able to replace one, two or twenty letters depending on what String I give it.

Comment: @James To be clear, you're wanting to replace every instance of the search char with its replacement, or perform the replacement a specific number of times?

Comment: An example might make things clearer:

Say I had the String “cupcakes”

I might want to replace the c’s with r’s and the a with s but leave the rest.

Or with “blackbird”

I might want to replace the b’s with z’s; the l with y; the a with q; the c with m; and the r with w.

i.e. each occurrence of a letter needs to be replaced with another letter, and two different letters can never be replaced with the same letter i.e.

In “scaffold”

I can’t replace the s with h and also the f’s with h as well.

Comment: @James What I have here will do what you want, but without checking the case of `[('s', 'h'), ('f', 'h')]` case.  For that, you'll want to pre-process the list of pairs of chars and remove any repeats.  An easy (but slow) solution would be to use `Data.List.nubBy`, but since I doubt you'll have more than a handful of pairs to replace, the poor efficiency won't even be noticed.

Comment: @bheklilr I'm still kind of lost?

Comment: @James Are you stuck trying to fill in `replace1` or are you stuck using `replace1` to build `replace`?

Comment: I'm still stuck on replace1.

Comment: @James `if c == findChr then replaceChr else c` is what you're looking for.  For the next part, you just need to repeatedly apply `replace1` with each pair of characters.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand lambdas. Can anyone recommend a good explanation? I tried Hoogle but that doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: @James A lambda is an anonymous function, meaning it's just a function without a name.  The `(\args -> expr)` syntax is used for defining them in line.  Between the slash and the `->` is where you put your arguments, the same as you would in a normal function, and after the `->` is where you put the body of the function, the same as you would a normal function.  Think of it as slash replacing the function name and `->` replacing the equals sign.  You can't use a `where` inside the lambda, but you can use `let ... in ...` within the lambda.  That's all there is to them.

Comment: @bheklilr what about the type declaration i.e. "::"?

Comment: @James The type declaration isn't always necessary and is usually just for clarity.  Typically, lambdas are kept short and can fit in one line.  You can put in a type parameter like `((\x -> x + 1) :: Int -> Int)`, but that's hard to read and isn't gaining you anything.

Comment: BTW there is a \ before the (f, r) I don't know why it didn't come out in my previous message. I can't edit it anymore either. Also, I don't have a clue how to put it in a grey box like it should be?!

Comment: Almost, you should have `replace [] text = text` to handle the base case and `replace (fr:frs) text = replace frs (replace1 fr text)`.

Comment: @bheklilr I don't follow? So I don't need what I wrote initially?

Comment: @James check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/431883bac287fe5cebba), it has a longer explanation than I can put here.  Also, to keep stackoverflow from getting too annoyed with the long comment chain, if you have any more questions feel free to email me at bheklilr2@gmail.com.