# Substitue String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Evening,

This is my attempt at an equivalent of "str_replace" in Haskell

```
strReplace :: (Char, Char) -> String -> String -> String {- Original (y) Parsed (z) -}
strReplace _ "" y = y
strReplace x y z = if (y !! 0) == fst x then strReplace x (drop 1 y) (z:([snd x])) else        strReplace x (drop 1 y) (z:(y!!0))
```

Essentially, the first Tuple is the char to be substitued (Ie  ('A', 'B') replaces all As to Bs, the second parameter is the String to be parsed and the third parameter should always be left an empty string. Compiler returns

```
*** Expression     : z : [snd x]
*** Term           : z
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : Char
```

Ideas? :)

Comment: What's unclear about this error message?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476723/find-and-replace-in-haskell/19478400

Comment: @bheklilr Disagree.  He's not asking how to write it, or if there's a function that already does it, just what is causing the error.  No such error in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `z : [snd x]` is incorrect, `z` is a list but `:` wants it to be an element. This can be fixed by using `z ++ [snd x]`.

If seeing the type signatures helps

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Or in your specific case

```
(:) :: Char -> String -> String
(++) :: String -> String -> String
```

---

If I may suggest a few improvements to your code however,  first `strReplace` shouldn't force you to pass an empty string

```
strReplace :: (Char, Char) -> String -> String
```

Next, we can do this two ways, using higher order functions or explicit recursion.

```
-- recursion
strReplace _ "" = "" -- Base case
strReplace (a, b) (c:cs) | a == c = b : strReplace (a,b) cs
                         | otherwise = c : strReplace (a, b) cs
```

So here if the string is empty we're done, otherwise we pattern match, if the first character is the one to be replaced, we replace it and recurse, otherwise we don't replace it and recurse.

This can actually be done much more cleanly with `map` though

```
strReplace (a, b) s = map (\c -> if c == a then b else c) s
```

This works identically to our previous version, but `map` abstracts out the looping logic.

Answer (score 1):

z is of type `[Char]`.  You can't use `:` to cons a `[Char]` into a `[Char]` - look at the type signature for `:`.  You would have to use `++` to append one `[Char]` to another.

Additional points:

1. It would be better style for `strReplace` to have a signature `:: Char -> Char -> String -> String -> String`.
2. It would be even better style for the signature to be `:: a -> a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`
3. You shouldn't require the calling code to pass in an empty string.  What if they don't - how will they know they made an error?  If your recursive call requires it, use an inner function (using `let` or `where`).
4. Where you see a function that looks like `foo x y = if (y == ... ) ... else ...` it can almost always be improved by either pattern matching or guards.

To expand on point 4, you could rewrite that third line as

```
strReplace x y z | y !! 0 == fst x = ...
                 | otherwise = ...
```

Even better, if you took my advice in point 1 and split the tuple into two simple `Char` parameters, you could do this:

```
strReplace x1 x2 y@(y1:ys) z | x1 == y = ...
                             | otherwise = ...
```

Comment: I didn't check your code for any other errors, just answered the basic question and added some style tips.  Can you see the point behind tip 2?